# error : String index out of range, Why?

Tags: java, substring

Search haebwado moreugeteoseo heck raises questions.

my code

```
int nTimeIdxNum = -1;

                try {
                    nTimeIdxNum = k.indexOf("x22T:");
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

                if (nTimeIdxNum > -1) {
                    String local_date = "";
                    System.out.println("k.length() = " + k.length());
                    System.out.println("nTimeIdxNum = " + String.valueOf(nTimeIdxNum));
                    try {
                        local_date = k.substring(nTimeIdxNum, 13);
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
```

}

and Console result

---

k.length() = 952
nTimeIdxNum = 495
String index out of range: -482

---

Why if an error occurs long enough length..
please help me

Answer (score 2):

In

```
k.substring(nTimeIdxNum, 13);
```

The second index must be larger than the first.

Perhaps you meant to write :

```
k.substring(nTimeIdxNum, nTimeIdxNum + 13);
```

This will give you a sub-string of 13 characters starting at the `nTimeIdxNum`'th character of the original `String`.